# enumerating strings of legnth K from an alphabet

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two elements, let's say [0,1] and I want to construct all possible combinations of length 2k with the same number of these two elements. For example, let 2k=6 and our output should be like  `(0,0,0,1,1,1) ,(0,0,1,0,1,1),(1,1,1,0,0,0) etc.`
I was trying to use something like this `[x for x in itertools.product([1,0], repeat=6)]` but it gives me all possible sequences(the number of ones and zeros may not be the same). Is it possible to somehow immediately create a list with a given property?

Comment: have you tried itertools.permutations?

Answer (score 1):

Try itertools.permutations, like below:

```
import itertools

def perms(k):
    l=k//2*[1] + k//2 * [0]
    m=[i for i in itertools.permutations(l)]
    return list(set(m))
```

Output for k=6:

```
>>> perms(6)

[(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)]
```

The code can be adjusted to work with more general structures (more elements, other than [0,1] etc. Let me know if you need any help with that.

Comment: But for k=6 I want the length of the list be 6

Comment: Sorry, i meant for k=4. I changed the answer. I chose k=4 as k=6 gives a lenghty result, not proper for illustration.

Comment: we get a lot of duplicates with this approach, can we get rid of them?

Comment: Done. I also changed the output to k=6

Answer (score 0):

Saying a list of length `2k` with equal number of elements `[a, b]` is equivalent to saying you want to a list with `a` in `k` positions and `b` in the other. So we can generate a list full of `a`'s or `b`'s and find all the possible combinations how to put `k` elements of the other variable in this list. This set of possible combinations is the same as selecting a set of `k` indices from the range `[0, ..., 2k]`. For the mathematics around this see [1].

```
from itertools import combinations

k = 6
assert k // 2
a = 0
b = 1
l = [
      [a if i in combination else b for i in range(k)] 
      for combination in combinations(range(k), int(k/2))
]
```

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination